# replacing data frame values with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What I'm trying to accomplish is a conditional check that looks at the value in the amount column. 
If the value in df['amount'] is less than 200k, nothing is done. 
If the value in df['amount'] is greater than or equal to 200k, replace the corresponding with either the value in months or 36.00 depending on whichever is greater.

```
import pandas as pd
df['amount'] = [332374.00, 22250.75, 45282.10, 339720.00, 1100.00, 40000.00, 15000.00, 207820.00, 497432.00]
df['months'] = [18.00, 17.00, 16.00, 46.00, 14.00, 13.00, 13.00, 13.00, 12.00]
df['checks'] = [1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.00, 1.00]
```

The desired output is a dataset that looks like this.

```
amount      months  checks
332374.00   36.00   1.00
22250.75    17.00   0.00
45282.10    16.00   0.00
339720.00   46.00   1.00
1100.00     14.00   0.00
40000.00    13.00   0.00
15000.00    13.00   0.00
207820.00   36.00   1.00
497432.00   36.00   1.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `loc` to find instances where the amount exceeds your 200k threshold and where months is less than 36. Then just set those values to 36.

```
df.loc[(df['amount'] >= 200000) & (df['months'] < 36), 'months'] = 36
>>> df
      amount  months  checks
0  332374.00      36       1
1   22250.75      17       0
2   45282.10      16       0
3  339720.00      46       1
4    1100.00      14       0
5   40000.00      13       0
6   15000.00      13       0
7  207820.00      36       1
8  497432.00      36       1
```

**Timings**

Using `assign` will be slower because you have to copy the entire dataframe and then assign the new column.  Using `loc` will be faster.

Here are the timings on this small dataset:

```
%timeit df.assign(months=df.months.mask(df.amount.ge(2E5), np.maximum(df.months, 36)))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

%timeit df.loc[(df['amount'] >= 200000) & (df['months'] < 36), 'months'] = 36
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 838 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice explanation!  I often use `assign` so that I don't overwrite my dataframe.  But this is a great reason why you may want to overwrite the current dataframe.

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution that worked for me. I just wanted to say thank you to both of you and that I appreciate the help. Very cool implementation.

Answer (score 3):

[**`pd.Series.mask`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) allows you to mask values of the series in the position of the `True` values passed in the `cond` argument.  You can also pass an `other` argument to supply the value to replace the ones being masked.  I used `np.maximum` to generate the `other` values.

```
df.assign(months=df.months.mask(df.amount.ge(2E5), np.maximum(df.months, 36)))

      amount  months  checks
0  332374.00    36.0     1.0
1   22250.75    17.0     0.0
2   45282.10    16.0     0.0
3  339720.00    46.0     1.0
4    1100.00    14.0     0.0
5   40000.00    13.0     0.0
6   15000.00    13.0     0.0
7  207820.00    36.0     1.0
8  497432.00    36.0     1.0
```

---

See also [**`pd.Series.where`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) as we could have performed the same task with:

```
df.assign(months=df.months.where(df.amount.lt(2E5), np.maximum(df.months, 36)))

      amount  months  checks
0  332374.00    36.0     1.0
1   22250.75    17.0     0.0
2   45282.10    16.0     0.0
3  339720.00    46.0     1.0
4    1100.00    14.0     0.0
5   40000.00    13.0     0.0
6   15000.00    13.0     0.0
7  207820.00    36.0     1.0
8  497432.00    36.0     1.0
```

---

We can also perform this task using the same logic but utilizing [**`numpy.where`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
a = df.amount.values
m = df.months.values
df.assign(months=np.where(a < 2E5, m, np.maximum(m, 36)))

      amount  months  checks
0  332374.00    36.0     1.0
1   22250.75    17.0     0.0
2   45282.10    16.0     0.0
3  339720.00    46.0     1.0
4    1100.00    14.0     0.0
5   40000.00    13.0     0.0
6   15000.00    13.0     0.0
7  207820.00    36.0     1.0
8  497432.00    36.0     1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Though i went with the other solution, I appreciate your time and detailed explanation. I will have to read up on the assign and mask more.

Comment: No problem at all, I'm glad you found an answer.